# Right way to get var[a][b][c] when keys may not exist

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyspark, dry, idioms

I have a nested data structure (a DynamicRecord, but I think it might as well be a nested list or anything else you can index with `object.__getitem__`) and would like to extract a value from it. Let’s call it var:

```
extracted = var[a][b][c]
```

will work just fine if var[a], var[a][b], and var[a][b][c] exist. So I can do

```
try:
    extracted = var[a][b][c]
except:
    extracted = None
```

But I have to do this many times (with different a, b, c and possibly more or fewer nestlings) and it seems repetitive. What’s the most Pythonic way to do this?

At the moment I’m calling a variadic helper function

```
extracted = drill_down(var, a, b, c)
```

but is this really the best way?

Comment: so `a,b,c` are variables, not strings? and I guess a DynamicRecord is like a `dict` object?

Comment: It's probably the best way. Python doesn't have shorthand syntax like JavaScript's optional chaining.

Comment: do you have control over implementation for DynamicRecord, or is it coming from a third party library?

Comment: @rv.kvetch Third-party (pyspark).

Comment: Yes, I think a helper function is the best way.

Answer (score -1):

One option is to create a custom `__getitem__`, to support dotted notation for nested `dict` access. This will ensure that no `KeyError` occurs when accessing a path, nested or otherwise. You can use this approach to customize default or desired behavior, such as below.

```py
class DynamicRec(dict):
    pass


def __new_getitem__(self, item, _get=DynamicRec.__getitem__):
    if not isinstance(item, str):
        # not passed in a `str`, just call the default __getitem__()
        return _get(self, item)

    result = self

    try:
        # split string on dot, iterate over each part
        for key in item.split('.'):
            result = _get(result, key)
    except KeyError:
        # if any path doesn't exist, return None
        return None

    return result


DynamicRec.__getitem__ = __new_getitem__


rec = DynamicRec(k1=DynamicRec(k2='value'))

print(rec['k1.k2'])  # value
print(rec['hello.world.!'])  # None

a, b, c, d = 'Th1s', 'is', 'a', 'TEST !!'
assert rec[f'{a}.{b}.{c}.{d}'] is None
```

Comment: So your suggestion is to replace every pyspark DynamicRecord with a weird custom type? I'm sorry but I think the cure is worse than the disease here.

Comment: @wim fair enough, i agree that would probably be time consuming to basically throw the game board out and start with a fresh one. there's probably a better plan out there though.

Comment: @wim check out my edit above. I'm not sure if it's any better from what the OP had in mind though.